# Blur a select after change in Internet Explorer 6

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-6

Simple question really. This works in all but IE6:

```
<html>
<body>
</body>
<select id="test" onchange="blur()">
<option name="one">One</option>
<option name="two">Two</option>
<option name="three">Three</option>
</select>
</html>
```

Is there anyway to get this working in IE6? JavaScript and JQuery hacks allowed.

Any ideas, remarks or tips?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you're missing some code there.

Comment: the blur() isn't working. Sorry should have specified more clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#test').change(function() {
        $(this).blur();
    });
});
</script>
```

Or you may try replacing:

With:

```
<select id="test" onchange="javascript:blur(this);">
```

**UPDATE**: Actually it seems that the IE6 JavaScript engine has problems with blur()

A (non-ideal) work around is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#test').change(function() {
        $('body').focus();
    });
});
</script>
```

Which will lose focus on the select input field by focussing the HTML document.

Comment: Two mistakes in the non-jQuery version: 1) do not use a `javascript:` prefix in an event handler attribute. The value of the attribute should be pure JavaScript. 2) You should call the blur() method of the select object, not the window (which is effectively what you're doing), and I'd be surprised if what you've got there works in any browser.

Comment: Actually I think I may be wrong about the second point: I think selects do not have a blur() method. Still, attempting to make the whole window lose focus seems odd.

Comment: hi this is closest to what we ended up using, which was body.blur() or document.body.blur().

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="test" onchange="blur()">
```

You want to blur the select, not the window (which acts as the global object, so this is the same as `window.blur()`).

```
<select id="test" onchange="this.blur();">
```

Works in all but IE6 due to a bug. You could get around it by focusing something else:

```
<a href="#" id="x"></a>
<select id="test" onchange="var x= document.getElementById('x'); x.focus(); x.blur();">
```

BUT! Either way, don't do this. You'll break keyboard accessibility for the select (since pressing up/down immediately sends a change event). This is the same problem that faces drop-downs abused as navigation.